# Google Search Console reports blocked resources from DoubleClick while rendering my pages, where do these calls come from?

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

I'm seeing errors when rendering pages:

> Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Here's a list:
>   url: `https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js` type: Script  reason: Blocked
>
> url: `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id` type: AJAX reason: Blocked

I have heard that it is  normal to see these errors but where are these files coming from in the first place? I haven't installed anything from doubleclick.net.

Comment: I'd like the answer to that too. If you say to use an alternative video source instead of youtube, the video error is different. --**blocked by CORS policy**: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**....I have robots.txt error files identical to the above. I have been searching for an answer for weeks and weeks...please someone from Google provide an answer. I have sent screenshots to Google several different occasions -- no answer from anyone at Google..very frustrating.

Answer (score 6):

Doubleclick is subsidiary of Google, which develops and provides Internet ad serving services. Using Adsense with dynamic allocation and targetting will automaticlly receive more relevant adds from the Doubleclick network.

The reason that Google Search Console is nagging is because one or several resources are blocked, these can be internal resources or external such as Doubleclick, if you take a look at the robots.txt on their server (https://static.doubleclick.net/robots.txt), you can see that they do not want their resources indexed, therefore, you see this message in your control panel.

Summary

Nothing to worry about if you are using advertising on your site.

Comment: but that was my point - it's an amazon affiliate site - that's the only advertising, I have never installed anything from Doubleclick nor adsense.

Comment: Amazon uses Doubleclick... and [many other 3rd party advertising networks](https://advertising.amazon.com/ad-specs/en/policy/approved-3p-ad-servers).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### Crawl Error

I have same problem.
Googlebot couldn't get all the resources for my page.

Block URL: `https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js`

Block URL: `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id`

### YouTube Script

I think there is an embedded YouTube video in your page. That could be responsible for that script. Remove it or use another video platform.

Comment: Is there a reason that you think the "embedded YouTube video" is responsible for this? You said you had the same problem, is that how you solved your problem? If so, which platform did you switch to?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, got the solution,  after a few brain storming i found that the solution was very simple- in my case at least :)- .
The video embedded through wp elementor plugin, i changed the privacy option settings from default to "on", yes it was that simple!